# Error when opening Minergate-gui on Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, qt, cryptomining

I'm trying to install Minergate-GUI on my Debian 9 to mine some coins. I downloaded the Minergate-GUI installation file `MinerGate-xFast-GUI-1.5-ubuntu.deb` (yes Ubuntu) from the official website and installed it using

```
sudo dpkg -i MinerGate-xFast-gui-1.5-ubuntu.deb
```

But when I try to open it, I get the error:

> minergate: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.9' not found (required by minergate)

I've installed libQt5Core version 5.9 manually, but I get the same error.
Is there any way to fix it or does Minergate have no support for Debian 9?